# Sharing localhost with Code With Me by JetBrains

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, pair-programming

I was trying to host a Code With Me session to build Angular app together. When I tried to forward ports there was only the TCP Protocol and I could not get it to get preview to show on his PC.

I would want to get the Angular preview to show on his PC. How can I do that?